# Django Password Reset through TastyPie API causing tags in email to render incorrectly

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, tastypie

I've built a password reset function for a django system that is exposed through a tastypie api. The rendering process looks like this

```
form = PasswordResetForm({'email': reset_email})
    form.full_clean()
    form.save({
        'use_https': request.is_secure(),
        'token_generator': default_token_generator,
        'from_email': settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
        'email_template_name': 'registration/password_reset_email.html',
        'request': request
    })
    return self.create_response(request, { 'success': True })
```

I've used the standard Django password reset email template. When I call the endpoint, the http request gets rendered in some of the custom tags e.g

Markup:

```
{% trans "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb36=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}
{% trans "Your username, in case you've forgotten:" %} {{ user.get_username }}
```

Expected result:

> Please go to the following page and choose a new password:
>   httt://www.myurl.com/password-reset
>   "Your username, in case you've forgotten: User Name

Actual result

> Please go to the following page and choose a new password:
>   httt://{'request': , POST:, COOKIES:{}, META:{'CONTENT_LENGTH': '48', **(...)**
>   "Your username, in case you've forgotten: **User Name**

It strikes me as odd that the model based template tags render correctly, but the global ones (e.g. 'Site_name') and the reset url & token seem to break. I'm sure that's a good clue as to the cause of the problem, but I don't know where to go next.

Would be great if anyone can help.

Thanks